# html(val), text(val), append(content) and the others

Tags: jquery

This question might sound subjective but I really do need to make a choise and in order for me to do that, I need some experienced voices.

Is there a resource, link or opinion that describes when and considering what issues to use the jquery's html(val), text(val) and append(content) for injecting content into an element?

are these comperable? or they are all designed for separate tasks?

regards,

kem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, [html(val)](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html#val) replaces the **html** content, [text(val)](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append#content) inserts text (not tags) always while [append(val)](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append#content) appends html content to the existing html content.
They are different features html(val) being the most powerfull.

Comment: in that case why replaceWith(content) exists? if html(val) already handles just that ?

Comment: replaceWith replaces the element, html() replaces the element's content.

Answer (score 0):

**text(val)** == [innerTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533899(VS.85).aspx) (only works on IE, so jQuery made it possible cross-browser)

**html(val)** == [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.innerHTML) (works like this DOM method)

**append(val)** == [Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.appendChild)

> *are these comperable?*  
>  well, you might compare in some cases
>   html(val) to text(val), 
>  but in
>   some cases text() can't replace
>   html().

> *or they are all designed for separate tasks?* 
>  Yes, they are designed
>   for separate tasks, see some examples
>   at [visualjquery](http://www.visualjquery.com/)